# iCloud with Core Data

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

this question was asked a year ago, but I have a specific question about online/offline syncing.

Device A & B are both offline, and you make independent changes to the model, lets say you connect device A first, so those changes sync to the cloud.

Now you connect device B, now those changes need to be merged with the changes existing on the cloud (not simply replace the cloud, because they have changes as well)

Does iCloud take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the idea, Core Data works with iCloud and merges any changes, resolving conflicts by choosing a winner. You don't get to help choose the winner, but you get notified if/when any new changes are available to your app.